# Como criar relacionamento entre dados diferentes para executar uma ação?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

**Esta instrução me retorna a sigla do estado: SC**

```
$("#billing\\:city").val(dados.uf);
```

**Tenho um select assim que não posso mudar:**

```
<select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]">
   <option value="">Por favor, selecione o estado</option>
   <option value="485">Acre</option>
   <option value="486">Alagoas</option>
   <option value="487">Amapá</option>
   ...
   <option value="507">Santa Catarina</option>
</select>
```

**Como eu poderia criar um relacinamento entre a sigla e o código do estado pra selecionar o estado da sigla?**

Como

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas você pode criar atributos dentro de uma tag html.

O que eu quero dizer é isso:

```
<select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]">
   <option value="" data-sigla="">Por favor, selecione o estado</option>
   <option value="485" data-sigla="AC">Acre</option>
   <option value="486" data-sigla="AL">Alagoas</option>
   <option value="487" data-sigla="AP">Amapá</option>
   ...
   <option value="507" data-sigla="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Essa resposta está correta, porém uma curiosidade que eu acho legal que os usuários tomem conhecimento e inclusive já sugeri como edição, é sempre utilizar o prefixo 'data-' para atributos inventados pelo usuário na tag html. Apesar de funcionar sem esse prefixo, existe esse padrão para dados privados do usuário, e o navegador nem tenta interpretar quando temos esse prefixo definido. 


Fonte: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp